# migrate existing user accounts from database (Passwords are hashed) to AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to migrate existing user accounts from database (Passwords are hashed) to AAD B2C. Does graph API support this, migrating hashed passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Active Directory  doesn't support this for now. If this is very important to you, you can vote it in [Custom Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/14603721-add-hashed-password-migration-to-azure-ad-b2c). Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

> Does graph API support this,

Now we can migrate user accounts with hashed passwords to Azure AD B2C now.

See more details about a new guide to User migration to Azure AD B2C in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration).

> migrating hashed passwords?

**NOTE:** We still cannot migrate the hashed passwords to Azure AD B2C. After migrating the accounts to Azure AD B2C, we need to reset passwords of accounts.

Comment: HI,@santosh vatsavai , If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as an answer to help more people. Thanks!

Comment: There's a [new guide: User Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration), that might be useful.

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration

Comment: HI, @santosh vatsavai .Thank you.It's a very new guide and I even didn't know it. I've read this document now. This guide shows how to migrate existing user accounts but not with its Hashed passwords. So you stll need to reset your passwords. I will update this answer . This can help more communities! Also thanks for spottedmahn 's comment.